# How to most efficiently filter SQL queries based on another table?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-athena

I am trying to limit a query of millions of rows to some subset of these millions. I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (
accnt_numA string,   --ex: 8923747897423
valueA int      
);

CREATE TABLE tableB (
accnt_numB string,   --ex: 8923747897423
valueB int
);
```

I would like to only query values in tableB if their accnt_numB is in the `tableA`. Which of the following is faster:

```
SELECT * FROM tableB 
WHERE accnt_numB IN (SELECT DISTINCT accnt_numA from tableA);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tableB b
JOIN tableA a 
ON b.accnt_numB = a.accnt_numA;
```

I am using Amazon Athena.

Comment: I cannot answer your question but one hint: you should specify the tables from largest to smallest while ensuring two tables are not specified together that will result in a cross join

Comment: It might actually be faster to JOIN the tables. Or, if things are really slow, you might create another table that just contains the DISTINCT account numbers from Table A and reference that, to avoid having to DISTINCT. Another option is to remove the DISTINCT and see whether it is any faster. How is your data stored in S3? Is it in a columnar format like Parquet? Is it compressed or partitioned? The way you _store_ the data can have a bigger impact that the way you _query_ the data.

Comment: Did you try running both the queries? Which one returns the results faster?